# How to retrieve Counter64 object in pysnmp?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to get snmp data using pysnmp library of python. In the data some COUNTER64 objects are available which didn't get retrieve.

**command -**

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <ip address>:<port> xyz::pqr
```

**output -**

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.12.1 = Counter64: 2761552407
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.12.2 = Counter64: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.12.3 = Counter64: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.13.1 = Counter64: 2299496
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.13.2 = Counter64: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.13.3 = Counter64: 0
```

**using pysnmp -**

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                          CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                          UdpTransportTarget(('ip', port)),
                          ContextData(),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('.1.3.6.1.4.1.16136.13.5.1.200.1.51.1.12'))):
    if errorIndication or errorStatus:
        print(errorIndication or errorStatus)
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

**output -**

```
No SNMP response received before timeout
```

How I can retrieve COUNTER64 objects? Is I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can only work with Counter64 values over SNMP version 2c and 3. SNMP version 1 does not support that as per the RFCs.

To switch pysnmp into SNMPv2c, just set `mpModel=1` or drop the `mpModel` parameter to make pysnmp using the default (which is v2c).

Here is the [doc](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.hlapi.CommunityData).

Comment: @IIya Etingof- that means, what I want is not possible? because as per **snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <ip address>:<port> xyz::pqr** command it is version 1.

Comment: @kit Try running `snmpwalk  -v1 -c public demo.snmplabs.com IF-MIB::ifXTable` and compare it against `snmpwalk  -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com IF-MIB::ifXTable`. Proper SNMPv1 engine should just drop Counter64 values when running over SNMPv1. It looks this is what snmpwalk does.

Comment: @IIya Etingof- In my case, snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <ip address>:<port> xyz::pqr command will not drop Counter64 values. I'm able to retrieve all the values, only Counter64 values are not being retrieved. Is any other way to do that because in java, we can set SNMP4JSettings.setAllowSNMPv2InV1(true); property to true for that.

Comment: @kit Right, proper SNMPv1 engine should drop Counter64 values but leave values of other types. This is what both Net-SNMP and pysnmp do, as far as I my experiments go. If I understand your original question correctly, you wanted to fetch Counter64 values over SNMPv1. This would be against the SNMP standard and thus can't work with SNMP4J either.

Comment: @IIya Etingof- yes right. Let me know if any improvement happens in SNMPv1.

Comment: @kit SNMP v1 won't change, but everyone uses SNMPv2c or v3 nowdays. SNMPv1 is pretty much obsolete.

Comment: @IIya Etingof- OK. Thanks for your experiences and important information which you share.